# Duplicate Resources

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, android-theme

I am trying to build my Android app and am recieving this error:

```
Error:Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/src/main/res/values/dimens_orange.xml:dimen/tab_host_default_height, /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/src/main/res/values/dimens_finalbeertheme.xml:dimen/tab_host_default_height
```

And also this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':BeerPprtfolio:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/src/main/res/values/dimens_orange.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/src/main/res/values/dimens_orange.xml:dimen/tab_host_default_height, /Users/Mike/Documents/beerPortfolio/beerportfoliov3/BeerPprtfolio/src/main/res/values/dimens_finalbeertheme.xml:dimen/tab_host_default_height
```

This is after trying to import a custom theme from Android Holo Colors.

Comment: apparently, you are defining `tab_host_default_height` twice, in `dimens_finalbeertheme.xml` and in `dimens_orange.xml` (read the error.)

Answer (score 0):

You must eliminate one of dimen/tab_host_default_height in your dimens_orange.xml or dimens_finalbeertheme.xml, because they are duplicate.

Check your error "Error: Duplicate resources:"